# Connection to SQL Server 2008/2012 with dynamic ports

Tags: sql-server, networking, connection

My problem is that I can't connect to any SQL Server instance installed on our server (it has both 2008 and 2012) using dynamic ports. Static ports works well. Also, if you mention dynamic port number in connection string, you can connect. But connection failed (regular error "Network or instance-specific...") with named instance without port number.

I found the solution - run `sqlbrowser.exe -c` on the server. After that everything works until server restarts. How to solve or diagnose it?

P.S. Firewall is OFF.

**EDIT:**
Also, when I'm closing this tool, it becomes inavaliable again. I'm not always connected to server with remote desktop. Now it works only when I connected and started this tool. Looks not OK for me.

Comment: Setting autostart for sqlbrowser service should help you.

Comment: Do you mean just put it ("sqlbrowser.exe -c") into "StartUp" folder or something more intellegent? Does Microsoft help have some suggestions about this? I didn't find anything in help.

Comment: No; he means editing the sqlbrowser service's entry in the Services snapin so that it starts automatically.

Comment: `SQL Server Browser` is a service. You can go to `SQL Server Configuration Manager` then to properties of `SQL Server Browser` -> `Service` tab -> set Start Mode Automatic. If there is no such service (I don't remember if it's possible) you can install it with SQL Server installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to an instance without a port number, then the browser service must be running. The fix is simple. Set the browser service to start automatically in the services console or in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

With dynamic ports, the port number will change every time you restart the server.